# How can I remove turbo-boost from an AMD processor?

Tags: cpu, amd-processor, frequency, turbo-boost

I have been trying different ways, there are certain extensions but with my laptop are not compatible, my laptop is a legion 5, I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible and I thought that maybe with the cpupower and with the following command `sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 3200MHz` it would be possible to limit the processor frequency making the turbo boost is not activated as I have had problems of overheating, but I have not found a way to make this command run at startup ubuntu

Comment: This might help: https://www.dell.com/support/contents/en-us/videos/videoplayer/tutorial-on-disable-turbo-boost-within-bios/6176626459001#:~:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20restart%20the,within%20BIOS%2C%20restart%20the%20computer.